configuring odoo 17 in PyCharm
I would appreciate it if someone could suggest how to start Odoo development using PyCharm or any other IDE.
I have installed Odoo 17 and PostgreSQL 12 which comes along with odoo, but I am facing difficulties starting development in PyChar due to some path to .env which I dont know.
Tried to solve what is path to .env using youtube videos,documents and ChatGPT but not successful.

what OS are you using?

I managed to setup the development environment for Odoo 17.0 on a Linux machine yesterday, using this nice blog post:
https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-setup-odoo-17-development-environment-using-pycharm-in-ubuntu-22-04 So I recommend visiting the original post.
In short you would need to:
Install software packages and dependencies required for running Odoo
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install -y git python3-pip python3-dev python3-venv libxml2-dev \
libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev libsasl2-dev libldap2-dev build-essential libssl-dev \
libffi-dev libmysqlclient-dev libjpeg-dev libpq-dev libjpeg8-dev liblcms2-dev \
libblas-dev libatlas-base-dev npm postgresql postgresql-client wget git
$ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
$ npm install -g less less-plugin-clean-css
$ apt-get install -y node-less

$ wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb
$ dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.bionic_amd64.deb
$ apt-get install -f

Clone the repository and switch to branch 17.0
git clone https://www.github.com/odoo/odoo --branch 17.0

Ensure a connection to a database server (service)
Create a database user (odoo) and a database (odoo) for Odoo and grant the user privileges to that
Create a Python virtual environment for the project
$ cd odoo
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate

Install odoo requirements.txt


$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Create an odoo.conf that contains the necessary configurations (db, etc.) here is a template:

[options]
addons_path = ~/odoo/addons
data_dir = ~/odoo/data
db_name = odoo
db_user = odoo
db_password = password
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
http_port = 8070
To test the installation run the tests and make sure there are no errors.
./odoo-bin -c odoo.conf --db-filter=^odoo$ --test-enable --stop-after-init --log-level=test -i base

This command will run the ./odoo-bin script using the configurations in odoo.conf using the database odoo and run tests (--test-enable) and install the base modules.
After that you can proceed to configure PyCharm...
